# how to add multiple things using fly on checkbox in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to check few things using check box and get them when popup is closed, like below:

[image]

How could I do that?

Let's says i have one div and div contains items, when i do click on items, i want to show the checkbox and when i close that popup i need to retrive those selected things

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block;background-color:green">>
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by handling li element clicks (toggling a class with checked icon background)

```
var selectedItems = "";
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    selectedItems = $this.parent().find("li.selected").map(function() {
        return this.innerText || this.textContent;
    }).get().join(',');    
});
```

Create this css classes (similar):

```
li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.selected {
  background-image: url(http://www.pbsys.com.br/icon_checked.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
}
```

To get the currently selected items, just read that selectedItems variable